# click on element, trigger click on input select field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to fake click on element, to open select box with no success..
please advice how can i do it, if its even possible ?

this is my code:

```
<div class="filterField"> 
  <label for="sortBykind">labelName</label> 
    <select id="sortBykind" class="subjectListFilter"> 
      <option value="" selected="">Show All</option> 
      <option value="">subject 01</option> 
      <option value="">subject 02</option> 
      <option value="">subject 03</option> 
      <option value="">subject 04</option> 
    </select> 
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
</div>
```

i want to be able to click on the font awsome i tag and it will open the select box like somone just clicked on the select box with the mouse

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

**please advice ?**

i tried to do this code in Jquery, its not working

```
        $('.fa-angle-down').click(function (e) {    

        var elementToClickOn = $(this).prev();

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("test");

            e = $.Event('mousedown');
            e.keyCode= 13; // enter
            elementToClickOn.focus();
            elementToClickOn.trigger(e);

        }, 500);

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native select elment can't open via JavaScript.

You can simulate a select element by div.